# What forces act on the block?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I can not understand why the forces N1 and N2 act on the block. What are these forces and why did they appear?

[image]

Comment: N1 and N2 are tension forces, because strings pull on objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the system is in equilibrium, perhaps it is useful to imagine what would happen $\vec{N_1}$ and $\vec{N_2}$ weren't there. You would just have $m_1 g$ and $m_2 g$ acting on downward on the blocks. Agreed? Then the blocks would just fall to the ground. The same as an apple falling from a tree. To drive this point home, it's always useful to go back to Newton's 2nd law, i.e.

$\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$

What this equation is really saying is that what we call a "force", in this case is a vector with magnitude and direction, is really an acceleration in that direction, at that magnitude.

So now imagine again those two blocks hanging on that rope. They're not going anywhere if in equilibrium, and if not in equilibrium, they're probably not falling straight to the ground. So there needs to be some other force (or equivalently, acceleration) in the opposite direction to keep them in place. We usually call this the tension force.

I think the diagram is a bit confusing to label $\vec{N_1}$ and $\vec{N_2}$ twice pointing in opposite directions. If you're concerned only with the blocks, you need only consider the upward (+Y) pointing ones.

Comment: Maybe I didn't ask the question correctly. I meant the forces, which are next to the block and directed downward

Comment: those are the gravitational forces